# adding elements in nested lists

Tags: python

I have got a list containing nested lists like this :

```
[ [datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 10, 0, 0), 0.0011] , [datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 11, 0, 0), 0.0013 , [datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 12, 0, 0), 0.0014]]

etc..
```

How do I go about adding sub elements 2 by 2 like this :

sum(0.0011,0.0013) + 0.0014

then taking the result of this sum and adding it to the next sub element ?

I`m basically trying to compound the values .

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with [the `sum()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) and a [generator expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY):

```
>>>items = [[datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 10, 0, 0), 0.0011], [datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 11, 0, 0), 0.0013 ], [datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 12, 0, 0), 0.0014]]
>>>sum(item[1] for item in items)
0.0038000000000000004
```

## Edit:

If you want to print out the result of each stage of the summation, you want to use [`functools.reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (which, in 2.x is [the `reduce` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce)).

```
from functools import reduce
import datetime

items = [[datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 10, 0, 0), 0.0011], [datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 11, 0, 0), 0.0013 ], [datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 12, 0, 0), 0.0014]]

def add_printing_result(a, b):
    total = a+b
    print(total)
    return total

reduce(add_printing_result, (item[1] for item in items))
```

Which gives us:

```
0.0024000000000000002
0.0038000000000000004
```

Comment: thanks for that, however this would give me the total ( interesting though since I was going the long way around using a reduce function ) . How do I get it to print out each sum instead of the total ?

Comment: @Julz Edited to give that solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0, myarr = [ [datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 10, 0, 0), 0.0011] , [datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 11, 0, 0), 0.0013] , [datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 12, 0, 0), 0.0014]]

for(i in myarr):
    sum+=i[1]
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this (I'm no Python expert) but this should sum your values properly such that `sum` is the sub elements' sum.

Comment: This is pretty un-pythonic, and wrong, I'm afraid. ``var`` is not a keyword in Python (meaning that line is a syntax error, not to mention the list literal that doesn't add up to the right number of brackets), and when you are looping over a list, loop over it, don't loop over a range and then access with index.

Comment: Good points, thanks. I do mostly Javascript these days, hence the `var`.